# Using the Windows MP3 decoder with Un4Seen Bass.NET

Tags: c#, .net

I'm writing a media player that uses the Bass.Net wrapper for Un4Seen's Bass native audio API.
The library is all free for non-commercial use and I have the free license, but in the documentation it says that unless you tell Bass to use the MP3 decoder built into Windows, it requires that you to also get a separate license from the MP3 licensing organization.

However, I cannot find anywhere how to get Bass.Net to tell it to use the Windows decoder instead of the one built into Bass (that requires the license).

This is going to be an open source application and I don't want to have to get a license for something that's free.

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to some forums:

> With version 2.3.0.1 there are now two versions of the bass.dll available:
>
> a) the standard on in the main directory based on the BASS internal MP3 decoder
>
> b) the on the 'mp3-free' directory which is using the Windows based MP3 decoder

[Source](http://www.un4seen.com/forum/?topic=4932.msg44543#msg44543)

So, you should be able to simply replace the bass.dll with the version in the mp3-free directory, and it will use the windows mp3 decoder automatically.

---

**The information below the line is outdated.  Apparently, they got rid of the `BASS_CONFIG_MP3_CODEC` config in an earlier version of Bass.NET**

<strike>If you have the .NET API help chm (/help), you can look at the `BASS_SetConfig` method in the `Bass` class for more information on setting up configurations.</strike>

```
Bass.BASS_SetConfig(BASSConfig.BASS_CONFIG_MP3_CODEC, 1);
```

Interestingly enough, the `BASS_CONFIG_MP3_CODEC` value (supposedly of the `BASSConfig` enumeration), is listed in the Get/SetConfig methods, but not in the actual documentation of the enum.

Comment: Kinda weird that it would default to the decoder that you supposedly need an extra license to use. One would think it would make more sense to default to the decoder that is safer (legally speaking) to use since most would not realize they need to set that and end up violating the license without realizing it.

Comment: I updated my answer, due to the info being outdated.  It looks like they solved this by distributing two different versions of the bass.dll (this is the dll that is wrapped by Bass.NET)

Comment: And so they did... I never noticed that folder when I got it (or probably just wondered what it was there for an ignored it). Easy enough to fix... thanks!.